# KVM: How to update amount of cores/procs during runtime

Tags: centos, kvm-virtualization, vcpu

How do I increase the amount of cores/cpus of a vm without requiring a reboot.

Answer (score 3):

...fortunately the process is pretty straightforward.

**Prerequisites/preparation**

In order to increase cpu count during runtime you need to configure the VM to have a "maximum" vcpu count and a lower "current" cpu count. An example xml extract (modify using virsh edit ):

```
<vcpu placement='static' current='4'>16</vcpu>
```

**Perform the increase**

**Note! The change is not permanent. To perform a change that is maintained after a shutdown/start you need to also use virsh edit .**

To set the current cpu count:

```
virsh setvcpus --count n <domain>
```